# A space where no paths are homotopic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was just thinking about algebraic topology and was wondering: It is possible to find a Hausdorff space where no paths are homotopic?

Excluding trivial examples.

Comment: What examples do you consider trivial?

Comment: I was thinking this would hold for the totally disconnected spaces, where the only paths would be staying at the singleton points. So trivial in the sense that we are looking at the discrete topology.

Comment: But totally disconnected does not imply discrete, so I am not sure what you mean

Comment: I understand that, but discrete implies totally disconnected, I suppose we can just discuss any examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. I presume by excluding trivial examples you are asking for a space $X$ with two distinct points $x,y$ such that there is a path $\gamma$ from $x$ to $y$ (note that $x,y$ being distinct is not so important, if there is a nonconstant loop at $x$ automatically this is true by just picking $y$ to be the midpoint). Given any such space, there is a homotopy of paths from the constant loop at $x$ to $\gamma^{-1} \circ \gamma$. Clearly these paths are unequal, since their images are different.